# How to decompile nw.js binaries?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, decompiling, decompiler

I wish to inspect the source code of a few node-webkit desktop apps (binaries) for security purposes. How should I do so?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

No need to actually decompile compiled code. Node Webkit is open source, so you can go ahead and check the actual source code, published by the creators.
Check out [nw.js on GitHub](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/) ([nw-builder](https://github.com/nwjs/nw-builder) on Github as well if relevant).

Comment: NW.js itself is open-source, but **projects made with it** may not be. This is like telling someone to look at Firefox’s source code rather than a web page’s source. It’s in entirely the wrong direction.